# Crystal Reports formula for number of workdays between first day of current quarter and currentdate

Tags: crystal-reports, datediff, date-arithmetic, dateadd

I'm having trouble with this.  If I find an answer I'll include it in my post.
SQL to calculate number of days in current quarter, for instance. I can't figure it with Crystal Syntax which is where I fall short.

for starters,

SQL to get 1st day of current quarter

```
SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

SQL to get last day of current quarter

```
SELECT DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0))
```

update:

beginning of current quarter in Crystal syntax:

```
dateserial(year(currentdate),datepart('q',currentdate)*3-2,1)
```

end of current quarter

```
dateserial(year(currentdate),datepart('q',currentdate)*3+1,1-1)
```

Comment: I don't need to account for holidays.  I've just tried things in SQL but translating to Crystal is confusing.

Comment: @jawz101 Please post the formula you have so far and specific issues you're having with it.

Comment: added SQL example to original post.  I just can't figure out Crystal Syntax to do something similar.  Even having parts of it such as how to return beginning day of current quarter would help.


like `SELECT DATEADD("q", DATEDIFF("q", 0, getdate()), 0)`

in SQL returns 1st day of current quarter but Crystal Syntax is very confusing to me.

Comment: sorry... keep changing original post.  I'm done making changes to it but left it with an example of trying to get the 1st day of current quarter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer in all it's glory :)

```
DateDiff ("d", dateserial(year(currentdate),datepart('q',currentdate)*3-2,1),currentdate) - 
 DateDiff ("ww", dateserial(year(currentdate),datepart('q',currentdate)*3-2,1), currentdate, crSaturday) -
 DateDiff ("ww", dateserial(year(currentdate),datepart('q',currentdate)*3-2,1), currentdate,crSunday)
```

shorthand of the final formula:

```
Datediff("d", startdate, enddate) - 
Datediff("ww", startdate, enddate, crSaturday)-
Datediff("ww", startdate, enddate, crSunday);
```